# Using Java to parse GeoJSON for Android app

Tags: java, javascript, android, google-maps, geojson

I'm a novice Android developer working on an app that needs to parse GeoJSON data.  I read the Google documentation and several other sources on how to do this best and found this useful github project: 
https://github.com/JasonSanford/geojson-google-maps

However, it's written for javascript.  I'm using Android Studio and my current Google maps integrated app is purely in java.  Is it worth rewritting the javascript of that project to pure java? Or should I be using javascript to setup and alter the Google Map within my app?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a need to rewrite the JavaScript framework in Java. Any computing you need to do with the framework can be server-side, and you can then request the data from the server in JSON.

The Android sdk includes json packages for parsing json, documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Maps Android GeoJSON utility.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/geojson

Or if you need more parsing functionality, you can use the Android-GeoJSON library from cocoahero.
https://github.com/cocoahero/android-geojson